# How's this Economics? Type - I Error & Type - II Error: Pregnancy test analogy - is it legit?

Tags: discussion

I don't have five points. Please move this to your Meta?

Where's the economics or econometrics in [Type - I Error & Type - II Error: Pregnancy test analogy - is it legit?](https://economics.stackexchange.com/q/27677)? Why was it posted here? Doesn't it belong on math or statistics Stack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Econometrics questions are considered on topic here and this is an econometrics question. Econometrics also deals with the issues of type I error & type II error (see for example Verbeek (2008) a guide to modern **econometrics** pp 31. - and I don't think there is any econometric textbook that would omit discussion of these).

As you can see in our [help center](https://economics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), on page that defines what is on and off topic:

> Econometrics: Totally on topic, but especially for theoretical questions, you may subsequently try the "All of Statistics" .SE site Cross-Validated.

Here we simply have some overlap with the cross-validated site. Sites sometimes overlap. For example, you can often see people cross-posting programming questions relating to statistics on both Cross-validated and stack overflow because they fit both sites. Cross-validated.SE and Mathematics.SE also overlap (due to statistics being just applied  mathematics).   I would personally agree the question above is better fit for Cross-Validated but it is by no means off-topic by the  rules of the site.